# Able to ping exact endpoint from browser that I can't from subscribable

Tags: angular, typescript, url, uri, subscribe

I have a microservice that I have successfully tested that is returning a json from url/uri: http://localhost:8090/api/v1/movie/search?title=The%20Arrival%20of%20a%20Train%20(1896)&year=1896

I get a json back when I enter that directly in. Even when I enter it directly in as: `http://localhost:8090/api/v1/movie/search?title=The Arrival of a Train (1896)&year=1896` which is exactly how I'm sending it, via my actual typescript code. I have a call function my component that calls the service:

```
` this.movieService.getMovieByTitleYr(queryObj.title, queryObj.year).subscribe(movie => {
    console.log(movie +"    <---returned")
    this.Movie = movie; 
});`
```

and in my service it is as:

```
`public getMovieByTitleYr(title: string, yr: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`/api/v1/movie/search?title=`+title+`&year=`+yr);
    return this.http.get<any>(`/api/v1/movie/search?title=`+title+`&year=`+yr , {withCredentials: true})
}`
```

but for some reason "movie" is coming back as undefined ( [] in console). No error. But I can somehow hit the endpoint via the browser with the exact same syntax. I even did a con log of the uri sent via the http object and that returned the json I was expecting.

```
I also tried adjusting the syntax desperately.. 
`public getMovieByTitleYr(title: string, yr: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`/api/v1/movie/search?title=`+title+`&year=`+yr);
    return this.http.get<any>(`/api/v1/movie/search?title=${title}&year=${yr}` , {withCredentials: true})
}`
```

I've verified in the browser multiple times. I'm not sure what to make of it.

Is there something about escaping characters? or the nature of urls that I'm not understand?

Comment: try to send title like `encodeURIComponent(title)` instead of title in your service

Comment: so such as, 'get<any>(`/api/v1/movie/search?title=${ncodeURIComponent(title)}&year=${ncodeURIComponent(yr)}'?

Comment: yes, same as your comment but change `ncodeURIComponent` with `encodeURIComponent`